# Honda Accord 1998

Tags: honda, accord, radiator

When I took radiator cap off, antifreeze came up like a volcano. The car wasn't on, and hasnt been on a day. I can't find out what it is, help?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was there a reason that you open the radiator cap like that? Was the car overheating?

Comment: Just checking everything, I had to replace the temp gauge, and when i did that i started to leak antifreeze but i fix that and now this

Comment: Where was the leak from and how did you fix it?